# facebook.php error - session_start() - Header already sent

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I coded a facebook app in PHP with php-facebook sdk, that is working absolutely fine on my windows 7, wamp.

But, now i implemented it on the webspace running on linux, and i'm getting a session_start() cookie error.

```
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - 
headers already sent by (output started at /mydirectory/index.php:5) in 
/mydirectory/src/facebook.php on line 37
```

I'm not getting why I'm encountering this error.

Below is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC  
"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<?php
    require_once('src/facebook.php');
    $app_id = "MY_APP_ID";
    $app_secret = "MY_APP_SECRET";

    $config = array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'fileUpload' => true,  
    'cookie' => true
    );
    $facebook = new Facebook($config);
    $user_id = $facebook->getUser();

 // other content

 ?>
```

Comment: can you edit in the code you used for initializing the sdk.  "minus the actual secret key."

Comment: just a note, if you are using echo above the doctype or html tags it will throw that same error as well.

Comment: I have added my code. I'm not using an echo before doctype. But yes, I've not added html tags as it is, but everything including html tags are echoed.

Comment: Everything works fine on my localhost though. Is it possible that the actual online apache server needs some permissions or ports to be opened for facebook.php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot print HTML before sending headers, the proper way to do it will be

Example:

```
<?php
session_start();
//
require 'src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '135669679827333',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'cookie' => true, // enable optional cookie support
  ));
  try { $user = $facebook->getUser(); } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title></title>
<meta />
</head>
<body>
<content here>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's *possible* that your server needs some ports opened, but it's far more likely that your remote server simply has different error reporting settings than your local development setup. If the Facebook API generates an error, that will be echoed to the page and preempt any headers, including cookies. You can test this by adding @-symbols in front of the Facebook method call, like so:

```
$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = @$facebook->getUser();
```

A more robust, more permanent solution is the `try {} catch (){}` block that Shawn E. Carter suggests. It's my theory that Facebook has been chucking out an error every time, and due to your local configuration you haven't noticed. Fixing the cause of this error should be your priority.

Comment: It's almost certainly the answer Shawn gave, where he's outputting content early in the page before the session setup takes place

Comment: The asker implied very strongly that his code ran fine on his local testing machine but failed in production without modifications. Until his self-answer, this answer was a legitimate direction for inquiry.

Answer (score 0):

Though i didn't get it, but removing the following lines of code and additional blank line before opening the php tag solved the issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC  
 "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: It's explained in Shawn's answer. *The first sentence*: You cannot print HTML before sending headers, the proper way to do it will be

Answer (score 0):

another way to do it will be like this:

```
<?php
    ob_start();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
<meta></meta>
</head>
<body>

<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';
//YOUR FACEBOOK methods here

?>


</body>
</html>
```